# Load a chart when the two before are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, charts

I have two chart that are loaded by buttons, and I want to start the third (the % between the 2 before) when both are loaded, can some one give a way to add a control that look in the arrays if both are loaded so the third chart can load.

I hope to be clear

thanks

```
//first function (starts with a button)
function loadGrafico(array_Label, array_Risultati) {
    var grafico = document.getElementById("query1");
    var query1 = new Chart(grafico, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: array_Label,
            datasets: [
                {
                    backgroundColor: [

                        ],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    data: array_Risultati,
                    }
                ]
        }
    });
}
//second function (starts with a button too)
function loadChart(array_Label, array_N_valutazioni) {
    var crt = document.getElementById("query2");
    var query = new Chart(crt, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: array_Label,
            datasets: [
                {
                    backgroundColor: [

                        ],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    data: array_N_valutazioni,
                    }
                ]
        }
    });
}
//that's the function have to be loaded when the 2 before are loaded
function loadPercentuale(array_Label, array_Percentuale) {
    var grafo = document.getElementById("percentuale");
    var percentuale = new Chart(grafo, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: array_Label,
            datasets: [
                {
                    backgroundColor: [

                        ],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    data: array_Percentuale
                    }
                ]
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Which data you needs to pass in *loadPercentuale* function?

Comment: voglio passarli array_Label come ordinata e la percentuale tra array_Risultati e array_N_valutazioni in ascissa

Comment: Ok but you only have *array_N_valutazioni* in the second function, so I have to assume that you can execute the third one, only after the second one? Is that true?

Comment: only after the one and the second both are loaded

Comment: Can you please check my answer? I've passed 0 just for tests, but it's should work.

Comment: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'
 

loadPercentuale(array_Label,0);

it returns this after the first function

Comment: how do you calc **array_Percentuale**?

Comment: i'm searching a way to do that because the label is the same and i would do the % between the "y" of the first and second chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your comments and details, I think that you are looking for something like this:

```
 // tmpArray, starting values are just to let you see what I'll store in there.
var tmpArray=[['array_Risultati'],['array_N_valutazioni']];
var tmpArrayLabel=[];

// function to calculate percentage between array values
function getPercent(){
    var return_array = [];
    for(var i=0; i < tmpArray[0].length; i++)
        return_array[i] = parseInt(tmpArray[0][i]*tmpArray[1][i]/100); 
    return return_array;
}

//first function (starts with a button)
function loadGrafico(array_Label, array_Risultati) {
    tmpArray[0]=array_Risultati;
    var grafico = document.getElementById("query1");
    var query1 = new Chart(grafico, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: array_Label,
            datasets: [{
                    backgroundColor: [],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    data: array_Risultati,
                    }]
        }
    });
    // Verify if loadChart for this array_Label has been called to execute loadPercentuale
    if (tmpArrayLabel==array_Label) loadPercentuale();
    tmpArrayLabel=array_Label;
}

//second function (starts with a button too)
function loadChart(array_Label, array_N_valutazioni) {
    tmpArray[1]=array_N_valutazioni;
    var crt = document.getElementById("query2");
    var query = new Chart(crt, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: array_Label,
            datasets: [{
                    backgroundColor: [],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    data: array_N_valutazioni,
                    }]
        }
    });
    // Verify if loadGrafico for this array_Label has been called to execute loadPercentuale
    if (tmpArrayLabel==array_Label) loadPercentuale();
    tmpArrayLabel=array_Label;
}

// That's the function have to be loaded when the 2 before are loaded
function loadPercentuale() {
    var array_Percentuale=getPercent();
    var grafo = document.getElementById("percentuale");
    var percentuale = new Chart(grafo, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: tmpArrayLabel,
            datasets: [{
                    backgroundColor: [],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    data: array_Percentuale,
                    }]
        }
    });
}
```

> **OLD ANSWER (before comments and details)**

This should work, but my problem is that I don't know which values you want to pass in **loadPercentuale**

```
// Caching #percentuale element
var $percentuale=$('#percentuale');

//first function (starts with a button)
function loadGrafico(array_Label, array_Risultati) {
    $percentuale.data('loadGrafico',array_Label);
    var grafico = document.getElementById("query1");
    var query1 = new Chart(grafico, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: array_Label,
            datasets: [
                {
                    backgroundColor: [

                        ],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    data: array_Risultati,
                    }
                ]
        }
    });
    // Verify if loadChart for this array_Label has been called to execute loadPercentuale
    if ($percentuale.data('loadchart')==array_Label) loadPercentuale(array_Label,0);
}

//second function (starts with a button too)
function loadChart(array_Label, array_N_valutazioni) {
    $percentuale.data('loadchart',array_Label);
    var crt = document.getElementById("query2");
    var query = new Chart(crt, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: array_Label,
            datasets: [
                {
                    backgroundColor: [

                        ],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    data: array_N_valutazioni,
                    }
                ]
        }
    });
    // Verify if loadGrafico for this array_Label has been called to execute loadPercentuale
    if ($percentuale.data('loadGrafico')==array_Label) loadPercentuale(array_Label,0);
}

// That's the function have to be loaded when the 2 before are loaded
function loadPercentuale(array_Label, array_Percentuale) {
    var grafo = document.getElementById("percentuale");
    var percentuale = new Chart(grafo, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: array_Label,
            datasets: [
                {
                    backgroundColor: [

                        ],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    data: array_Percentuale
                    }
                ]
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: now the first and second chart don't show the results, and neither the third, there's the GET call but no chart starts

Comment: Buongiorno! I think I need to see more code to understand what you're doing... I mean where is the ajax call? Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Anyway, for now I think that must be some error with commas.. I've edited the answer. Try.

Comment: no way....but for the control I've done in an other way so now I only need the way to work out the percentage of array_Risultati and array_N_valutazioni, could you suggest me a way to work out that?

thanks

Comment: Just use the function **getPercent** I've done. But as I said, google: Vixed

Comment: Marco, this must works. If not must be some stupid comma. Check in the console.

Comment: @MarcoCasetta what was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why don`t you try a flag variables? This is not a better solution I hope, But it will help you somewhat. Place two flag variables in two functions which contain boolean values. Then make a call to the third function if both the variables returns true then the third function will load and you chart also load automatically

Comment: could you give me an example for this case?

Comment: function functionOne(){
    // after the result came for this function put two flag variables and assign true value to them.
     boolOne = true;
     boolTwo = true;
}
// now call two functions like
if(boolOne){ // call function2 }